# Getting Error 404 when calling a Api router in Nextjs 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I searched in articles and YouTube videos about how to fix error 404 when calling a API router for example `/api/hello/`

even when I saw the documentation in Next.js website I didn't find any solution for this problem, and I even create a new project from scratch, but the solution is still exist.

this is the simple API router code of `app/api/hello/router.ts`

```js
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.json({
    messsage: "hello world",
  });
}
```

I really need a help form this error

Comment: Do you have a middleware set up for your NextJS project?

Answer (score 0):

your api file should be `route.ts`

you have `router.ts`

so you actually do not have an api endpoint

Answer (score 0):

rename your file to route.ts instead of router.ts